# Фоново запустить в процессе выполнения php скрипта другой скрипт

Tags: php

Не могу сообразить как сделать данное.
В процессе выполнения php скрипта мне нужно запустить еще один php файл.

Работает так:

```
if ($curl = curl_init()) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/constructor/stickers/sticker.php?saveIm=1");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $out = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

Но мне кажется, чтобы запустить локальный скрипт есть более правильное решение.
Меня бы устроил вызов `include` с параметрами, но такое не работает.
Предопределение параметров перед `include` тоже не катит.

Comment: запуск должен быть синхронный? то есть результат работы дочернего скрипта будет использован в родительском?

Answer (score 0):

Начните с чтения мануалов по [pcntl_fork](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pcntl-fork.php) и [proc_open](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.proc-open.php). Можно погуглить `php async` и почитать первое что будет найдено - [Асинхронное параллельное исполнение в PHP](https://habr.com/post/278755/) . А ещё посмотреть в сторону [phpDaemon](https://habr.com/post/79377/) и даже [ReactPHP](https://reactphp.org/).